# snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is not working due to containerd on centos 8

Tags: centos8, microk8s, containerd

I installed microk8s on centos 8. While starting microk8s, it fails according to following error.

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011

$ microk8s inspect
Inspecting Certificates
Inspecting services
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-cluster-agent is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-control-plane-kicker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy is running
 FAIL:  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is not running
For more details look at: sudo journalctl -u snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
```

Once I run following command, `unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService` appears in logs.

```
$ journalctl -u snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
May 03 15:46:25 nestpaylab microk8s.daemon-kubelet[41600]: E0503 15:46:25.990540   41600 remote_runtime.go:86] Version from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
May 03 15:46:25 nestpaylab microk8s.daemon-kubelet[41600]: E0503 15:46:25.990622   41600 kuberuntime_manager.go:202] Get runtime version failed: get remote runtime typed version failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
May 03 15:46:25 nestpaylab microk8s.daemon-kubelet[41600]: F0503 15:46:25.990641   41600 server.go:269] failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: get remote runtime typed version failed: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService
```

As I checked from https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/261c107ffc4ff681bc73988f64e3f60c32233b37/docs/cri/crictl.md, it is related to incorrect containerd configuration from Docker installation.

So I ran following commands as shown but nothing changed.

```
$ mv /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd.toml /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd.toml.bak
$ containerd config default > /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd.toml
$ systemctl restart snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd.service
$ systemctl restart snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet.service
```

How can I fix this issue?